# Get the 2 options with min value for each each student_id

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table name `m_option`:

```
m_option_id  m_student_id  value
1             1             5
2             1             5
3             1             6
4             1             7
5             2             1
6             2             2
7             2             3
8             2             3
9             2             4
```

I want to get the 2 rows with min `value` for each `m_student_id`:

```
m_option_id  m_student_id  value
1             1             5
2             1             5
5             2             1
6             2             2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` window function for that:

```
SELECT m_option_id, m_student_id, value
FROM (
    SELECT
        m_option_id, m_student_id, value,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY m_student_id ORDER BY value)
    FROM m_option
) t
WHERE
    row_number <= 2;
```

`row_number` will calculate the number of each row within its group. We then use that number to filter the the top 2 rows (i.e. lowest `value`) from each group.

Alternatively, you could use a `LATERAL` subquery:

```
SELECT m_option_id, m_student_id, value
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT m_student_id FROM m_option) s,
     LATERAL (
         SELECT m_option_id, value
         FROM m_option
         WHERE s.m_student_id=m_student_id
         ORDER BY value
         LIMIT 2
     ) t;
```

This will go through all distinct values of `m_student_id` and for each one of them will find the top 2 rows using a `LATERAL` subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there can be ***many*** rows per student in table `m_option`, the key to performance is index usage. And that's most efficient if you have a **separate `student` table** listing all students uniquely (which you would typically have). Then:

```
SELECT m.m_option_id, s.student_id AS m_student_id, m.value
FROM   student s
    ,  LATERAL (
   SELECT m_option_id, value
   FROM   m_option
   WHERE  m_student_id = s.student_id  -- PK of table student
   ORDER  BY value
   LIMIT  2
   ) m;
```

A **multicolumn index** on `m_option` makes this *fast*:

```
CREATE INDEX m_option_combo_idx ON m_option (m_student_id, value);
```

If you can get **[index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans)** out of it, append the column `m_option_id` as last index item:

```
CREATE INDEX m_option_combo_idx ON m_option (m_student_id, value, m_option_id)
```

Index columns in this order.

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Distilling a unique list of `student_id` from `m_option` would incur an expensive sequential scan over `m_option` and void any performance benefit.

This excludes students without any related rows in `m_option`. Use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL () ON true` to include such students in the result (extended with `NULL` values for the missing option):

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

If you do not have a `student` table, the other fast option is a recursive CTE.
Detailed explanation for either variant:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: SQL92 has been out for a while, time to get rid of the old style joins?

Comment: @Andomar: The comma is [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) short notation for `CROSS JOIN` (binding less tightly). Nothing wrong with it. Explicit join conditions are preferable over generic predicates in the `WHERE` clause. But that's moot without join condition.

Comment: I agree that `cross join` is the case where the old style comma syntax has few disadvantages. But I don't think that justifies keeping SQL89 around. Mixing two styles is inconsistent and confusing for people learning SQL.